# Character encoding issue � appears instead of other character

Tags: unicode, upload, character-encoding, jakarta-mail, war

I am sending mail in spanish through Java mail API, when i send mail from localhost the characters in the received mail appears correct as 'Enlace de renovación de contraseña' but when i upload my WAR file on server and send mail the character in reeived mail appears like 'Restablecer tu contrase??a de IOS Social'. how to get rid of this. thanks in advance

Comment: We need a whole lot more details, like, where does the data in the email come from?  Is it the exact same program with hard coded Java string constants in each case?  Are you reading the data from a database or a web page?  Have you verified that the same data is being used for the content of the messages in each case?  Are you using the same versions of JavaMail and the same versions of the JDK in each case?

Comment: Thanks bill for your reply, i was sending the mail and setting its content and subject through javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage, i have solved the problem by setting the content and subject by these methods : message.setContent('your message','UTF-8')